# How to handle Sequelize nested/compound queries?

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

I'm a confused how to handle nested `WHERE`'s using Sequelize. The documentation doesn't really have an example of this. I have a query that looks like this:

`SELECT * FROM Users WHERE likes <= $likeVariable AND ( likes < $likeVariable OR id < $idVariable ) ORDER BY likes DESC, id DESC`

I need this query for cursor based pagination on a non-unique property `likes`, which is why I need the `id` property suggested [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/164755)

How do I convert this to my Sequelize query?

```
var users = await Users.findAndCountAll({
    where: ????, <- How do I do the WHERE clause?
    order: [['likes', 'DESC'], ['id', 'DESC']]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var users = await Users.findAll({
 where: {
  likes: {
   [Op.lte]: $likeVariable,
   [Op.and]: {
    [Op.or]: [
      {likes: { [Op.lt]: $likeVariable} },
      { id: { [Op.lt]: $idVariable } }
    ]
   },
  }
 },
 order: [['likes', 'DESC'], ['id', 'DESC']]
});
```

Comment: I think this almost works, but I receive an error stating: `"message": "Invalid value { id: { [Symbol(lt)]: 85 } }"` (I put in 85 as a dummy `id`. I guess I'm a little confused as to how that `[Op.or]` is related to the `[Op.lt]` above it?

Comment: make sense. I have fixed a little. I am glad that you found the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured it out, the mental hurdle was discovering that the `[Op.or]` doesn't have to be used within a property:

```
where: {
    likes: {
        [Op.lte]: $likeVariable
    },
    [Op.or]: [
        {
            likes: {
                [Op.lt]: $likeVariable
            }
        },
        {
            id: {
                [Op.lt]: $idVariable
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

As a result, my terminal prints out the following SQL query generated by Sequelize:

```
SELECT * FROM `Users` AS `User` 
WHERE (`User`.`likes` < 6 OR `User`.`id` < 85) 
AND `User`.`likes` <= 6 
ORDER BY `User`.`hypes` DESC, `User`.`id` DESC;
```

Thanks to Jiml for getting me on the right track!